# Drastically different results from summary.lmerModLmerTest vs anova.lmerModLmerTest

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme, differences

I am beginning in linear mixed model with lme4. Recently, I have encountered a problem where results obtain from summary.lmerModLmerTest and anova.lmerModLmerTest are drastically different. My model is as followed:

```
lmer (help.response~Condition*Detail_C+(dummy_img+dummy_img:Detail_C|participant)+(1|Story_ID),data= interaction.df)
```

Basically, I am looking at an interaction effect between a binary variable (Condition) with 2 levels and a within-cluster centered continuous variable (Detail_C).

I obtained the following from summary():

[image]

The main effect of Detail_C is far from significant but using anova(), it returned the following:

[image]

In this output, the main effect of Detail_C is significant.

I am really confused as to why there is such a drastic difference between them. Did I miss something or made a mistake somewhere? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: check what contrasts you're using for `Condition` ... ?

Comment: It's dummy coded

Comment: try sum-to-zero (effects) contrasts (`contrasts=list(Condition=contr.sum))`) ?

Comment: Ah of course, I can't believe I didn't make that connection anova() is effect coded. Thanks so much!

Comment: sounds like that might have fixed it?  In which case it would be great if you could post an answer to your own question (self-answering is encouraged).